# What affects the Brightbug's duration?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have found that in some circumstances, when I use a Brightbug, the effect may last several minutes, but in other circumstances, it might only last 30 seconds.

Does anyone know what might affect the Brightbug effect's duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [Dark Souls 2 Wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Brightbug). It states that:

> *The duration of the effect is 120 seconds, not affected by the Lingering Dragoncrest Ring.

So the Brightbug's effect will last for 120 seconds, or 2 minutes, not affected by the Lingering Dragoncrest Ring.  So it is supposedly last for two minutes, ***but*** it says that a glitch that may affect the duration is:

> The brightbug's duration seems to reset each time the player saves, and quits his, or her game.

This should be the reason your Brightbug's effect's duration is being changed. I can say that your shortened time length is really a glitch. No one nor I can reproduce your problem. For some reason, your enchantments just reset the duration to a lower time period. You might need to file a bug report. I hope this helps you now!

Comment: So, to clarify, if I quit with the brightbug effect (after say, 60 seconds), it will reset the duration, and effectively give me another 2 minutes, racking the overall amount to 3 minutes?

Comment: Probably so. It seems to be that way.

Comment: So why would it be lasting less? Like I said, sometimes it only lasts ~30 seconds. For example if I use a Resin on my weapon, it seems to cut the Brightbug duration short.

Comment: If you can reproduce it you can add an entry to the bugs list on that page.

Comment: @PythonMaster Any news on the *shortened* time length?